# C# List 1 has some records that list 2 contains list 3 must have 0 1 correspondingly

Tags: c#, list

My C# list contains object:

```
class Bot {
string name;
string oid; 
}
```

new List with 2 bots named:

```
0, name = Pro, oid = 100
1, name = Noob, oid = 200
2, name = Tard, oid = 300
```

I have also a list which contains list of OID (selected via some odd way)
List is this:

```
0, 200
1, 300
```

I need to create a new list like this:

```
0,0
1,1
2,1
```

Where list 1 index is maintained and list 2 is matched with the OID of list 1 and if it matches it must display 1 else 0.

How should i begin to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?.. Linq left join can help you, also a `select` with nested `where` can help

Comment: Im thinking.. I tried foreaching but i want linq only is that even possible?

Comment: yes... But you need to show some effort in creating that linq

Comment: Have you tried using intersect?

Comment: Show your attemps on the loop. Does it work as expected? Only then you should consider to simplify it using linq.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overload from [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) that also returns an index:

```
var result = myBots.Select((x, i) => new 
{ 
    Index = i, 
    Value = list2.Any(y => y.oid == x.oid) ? 1: 0 
});
```

However you may consider to use a `boolean` instead of a either zero or one that indicates if the element matches or not:

```
var result = myBots.Select((x, i) => new 
{ 
    Index = i, 
    ContainedInOtherlist = list2.Any(y => y.oid == x.oid) 
});
```